# How to mock a frame html using wiremock?

Tags: java, html, testing, frame, wiremock

I am trying to mock a html which includes frames using wiremock. These html files on resources/html folder. The html class is below,

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE>A simple frameset document</TITLE>
</HEAD>

<frameset cols="20%, 80%" rows="100">
    <frame id="leftFrame" src="/frame1.html">
    <frame id="mainFrame" src="/frame2.html">
</frameset>
</HTML>
```

What I was trying to do is:

```
 public MockUtils(String folder, String fileName) throws IOException {
    wireMockServer = new WireMockServer(options().port(8081));
    wireMockServer.stubFor(
        get(urlPathMatching("/([a-z]*)"))
            .willReturn(
                aResponse()
                    .withBodyFile("framesample.html")
                    .withBody(prepareResponse(fileName, folder))));

    wireMockServer.start();
  }

  private static String prepareResponse(String path, String folder) throws IOException {
    return getResourceAsString(folder + "/" + path);
  }

  private static String getResourceAsString(String name) throws IOException {
    return Resources.toString(Resources.getResource(name), Charsets.UTF_8);
  }
```

and what I get it:

[image]

So my question is, how can I add these frames on Wiremock?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue comes from an incorrect regex match.

`/([a-z]*)` will match `matchdetail` and `html`, but not `matchdetail.html` or `frame1.html`. You can instead do a matching group of `([a-z0-9.]*)` or `(.*)`, depending on how precise you want to be. I'd advise you to check out a regex tool if you aren't getting the matches you'd expect. My personal go-to is https://regex101.com/.

Comment: thanks, it was my bad on the regex. I have corrected the regex, but now it still does not show the frames properly. these frames files on the test/resources/http folder.

Comment: Hmm... Looking at it now, you're responding with both a bodyFile and body. I'd switch to just using bodyFile. I think you'll also have to update your file path. You'll either need to update your default `__files` directory, or just move the file underneath `__files`, which is by default under `src/test/resources`, so if you kept the `http` folder and moved it under `__files`, I think it'd be `.withBodyFile("http/framesample.html")`